# Oscillating block amplitude change when 2nd mass added

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

There is a oscillating block with amplitude $A$ and mass $M$. We add a mass $m$ with zero velocity and vertically.when the block is in this two conditions:

```
1-the blocks velocity is zero
2-the blocks velocity is maximum.
```

I want to figure out how does the amplitude changes.So in the first condition we know no momentum in the horizontal plan is given to the system and the energy is conserved because the velocity before and after the collision is zero so I think the amplitude would not change but imagine we have a large mass that we add.will the amplitude say the same?I can not accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the added mass is given the same velocity as the oscillating mass just before it is added, then there is no change in amplitude for either case. Only the frequency changes. i should point out that if the mass to be added is NOT given the velocity of the oscillating mass, then one would need to know each velocity and how elastic is the collision.

Comment: Assume that we add the mass with no initial velocity.like the block is moving in the horizontal axis and we add the mass with zero velocity vertically.please give some reasons.